# Getting null pointer exception while loading schema

Tags: xsd

public class TestValidatorSample {

```
public static void main(String aa[]) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder parser = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

    SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    //      /test_elements.xsd
    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(TestValidatorSample.class.getResource(
            "/xsds/pakagename/test_elements.xsd").toString()));

    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    DOMSource domsrc = new DOMSource(parser.parse(new InputSource("test-example.xml")));
    try {
        validator.validate(domsrc);
        System.out.println("Validation successfull!!!");
        //                  System.out.println(xmlFile.getSystemId() + " is valid");
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        System.out.println("Validation not successfull!!!");
        //                  System.out.println(xmlFile.getSystemId() + " is NOT valid");
        System.out.println("Reason: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at line 47.

I am getting a nullpointer(as mentioned above) exception while loading a schema.
In the above code snippet I am trying to load a schema which will be used to validate xmls generated in my application .

Can anybody please help me to find out why I am getting null pointer exception ?

Comment: Which is line 47 in the above code?